# Video autoplay not working - Trying to find a fix

Tags: reactjs, video

I have a video background in React. I want it to autoplay. Autoplay does not work.

I have tried:

1. autoplay
2. autoPlay
3. autoPlay="autoplay"

What I find particularly odd is that occasionally, it WILL work. But then it will stop.

Here is the code as it is right now.

```
<video loop autoPlay>
       <source src={require('../../videos/background.mp4')} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Here is the entire section of the component. I'm using a transition, but as of last week, it didn't impact it.

```
<div className="video-background">
    <Transition in={true} timeout={1000} appear={true}>
        {(state) => (
          <div id="banner" className="video-foreground" style={{ 
                            ...transitionStyles[state]
                        }}>
                        <video loop autoPlay>
                            <source src={require('../../videos/background.mp4')} type="video/mp4" />
                        </video>
          </div>
        )}
     </Transition>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have an anonymous function within your render? Is `state` not available beforehand?

Comment: Try adding muted to the video element. If that doesn't work, remove the sound encoding from the video entirely together with the muted attribute on the element. Take a look at these articles. https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: mute did it. Thanks you sir. That's an obnoxious detail to worry about

Answer (score 160):

Well in my case added **muted** property.

Try this:

```
<video ... autoPlay muted />
```

> Chrome 66 stops autoplay of all video that don't have the **muted** property.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm even in Player from 'video-react' like this '<Player src="/rain.mp4" autoPlay loop muted></Player>'

Comment: Works. In my case the mistake was i had autoplay (P) small letter. when i changed to autoPlay everything worked as expected.

Comment: It's not working in my case. I've added `muted` property as well. Do I need to include any specific library which I don't think is required? Any thoughts? @sergio-reis

Comment: It works for me.
FYI, this behaviour is also explained in MDN, "In some browsers (e.g. Chrome 70.0) autoplay doesn't work if no muted attribute is present."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Attributes

Comment: This didn't work until I added `={true}` to the various `<video />` tag properties, e.g. `muted={true} autoPlay={true}`.

Comment: After a long research, It working perfect. Thanks @Sergio Reis

Comment: THIS, should be the accepted answer! thanks.

Comment: Thank you, working fine now. UX wise this actually seems like a good idea, nobody ever mentions it though to be a necessity for modern browsers.

Answer (score 42):

In my case the video in React did not play because I didn't capitalize `autoplay`. It has to be `autoPlay`.

Comment: Oh my god! You are the truth

Answer (score 14):

Try this (it works):  `autoPlay={true}`

Comment: Sorry to hear that - are you aware of the curly brackets {...} and not parentheses (...)? It worked for me. Sorry in advance if this is a stupid comment :-)

Comment: When in doubt, read the f... look at the base class. In this case (assuming JSX), we start at `video` element, which extends `JSXBase.VideoHTMLAttributes`, which extends `MediaHTMLAttributes`, which extends-- wait. No need to go further. There is our `autoplay` property defined:

`interface MediaHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
        autoPlay?: boolean;
        autoplay?: boolean | string;
`
Unlike HTML where the element wants either the string "autoplay" or nothing, we see that JSX handles it differently.

Answer (score 9):

Try `<video loop muted autoPlay controls = ''> ... </video>`

Apparently, when placing the controls, it is possible to play the video, then placing the controls = '', we can remove the buttons from the controls and autoPlay works again.

Comment: works great in react , video autoplays and loops

Answer (score 7):

I used useRef and the problem of not playing the video was solved.

```
const vidRef=useRef();

useEffect(() => { vidRef.current.play(); },[]);

<video
  src="/videos.mp4"
  ref={ vidRef }
  muted
  autoPlay
  loop 
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

It works only when the video is muted so please add `muted` attribute

```
<div>
    <video src="/assets/loading.mp4" loop autoPlay muted className="h-[300px] w-auto" ></video>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to mute the video, consider the following reverse approach:

**Mute and later unmute in useEffect.**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
...

const vidRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
   vidRef.current.muted = false;
 }, []);

...
<video autoPlay controls loop muted ref={vidRef}>
    <source
       src={"/url_to_video.mp4"}
       type="video/mp4"
    />
</video>
...
```

> Works 100%

Answer (score 1):

> ## autoplay work with muted & controls

```
     <video controls  muted  autoPlay > 
              <source type="video/webm" src=".../.webm" />
     </video>
```

Comment: Same as the most voted answer. Nothing new.

Comment: @RitikBanger , It is not only working with "muted" or "controls = ' ' "  . must write proper  "controls"   to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well..
You can try this

```
autoplay=""
```

Like this

```
<video autoplay="">
       <source src={require('../../videos/background.mp4')} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

if  you  are   facing  this   issue  ,try  this  it  will   work  100%

```
<video
          src="/videos/ab.mp4"
          controls
          muted
          autoPlay={"autoplay"}
          preLoad="auto"
          loop
        > something</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you the solution

```
<video
  src="/videos.mp4"
  controls
  muted
  autoPlay={"autoplay"}
  preLoad="auto"
  loop 
 > </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding somethigs in the video body it works in my case.

```
<video
   src="/assets/videos/presentation.mp4"
   muted
   autoPlay
   loop >
      My brand like image alt
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the order in which you have it makes a difference too. I had autoPlay loop muted control and the video only worked on the computer with the control. Once I did ****muted autoPlay**** the video then played played on it's own as well as on mobile!

Answer (score 0):

```
import video from 'src/../../video'
    
<video muted autoPlay loop>
      <source src={video} />    
</video>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try `allow="autoplay"`