# React video not autoplaying, autoplay not working

Tags: reactjs, autoplay

I have a video component added like this

```
<video autoplay loop src="/vids/vid.mp4">
```

But it is not playing automatically.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259734/video-autoplay-not-working-trying-to-find-a-fix Try adding mute option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## This worked

- Use `autoPlay` instead of `autoplay` for react.
- Also add `muted`

So, the code will be `<video autoPlay muted loop src="/vids/vid.mp4">`

if you want to use the `autoplay` with small letters, you should assign the value `autoplay="true"`

Comment: How can i set unmuted. I have remove "muted" but, It does not sound on.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
I was working with ReactFullpage and the video would not autoplay on mobile devices.
so I added  `data-autoplay=""` and it got fixed.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `muted` attribute, like so:

`<video muted autoplay loop src="/vids/vid.mp4">`

For more, you can have a look:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video